# How to increase Cordova app Security

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, security

I am building an android app using cordova. User of this app will be able to login to remote server through this app & receive user information. user will have an wallet & they can purchase digital products from this app.

At the first instance, the app receive email address & password from user & send it to remote server for authentication. Here is a sample:

```
var did = device.uuid;
if(did!=''){
$.get("http://SERVER.ORG/Login.php?email="+email+"&pass="+pass+"&did="+did, getData);
}else{
alert("Sorry! can't read your deice. Please close the app & restart.");
window.location.href = "index.html";
}



function getData(data) {
 var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
 localStorage.status    = response.status;
 localStorage.usr_pin   = response.usr_pin;
 if(localStorage.status==0){
  alert("Invalid Credentials");
 }else{
  localStorage.user_id  = response.client_id;   
  localStorage.user_name    = response.client_name;     
  localStorage.user_phone   = response.client_phone;    
  localStorage.user_balance = response.available_credit;
 }
}
```

*** The first thing I need to ensure that no one can access my login url directly without app.**
Currently I am checking whether the request contains device ID or not. And blocking device ID with more than 5 failed attempts.

*** Secondly, I need to ensure that my login url is hidden from user.**
Currently, my login function is in a different .JS file hosted on my server. but the apk can be easily decompiled & html files are telling the location of my .JS file, which can be downloaded easily & decrypt using several online decrypter.

I've searched a lot and found several security tips, but due to lack of knowledge didn't get them properly. Please suggest me **how can I hide my source code from reverse engineers**. if its not possible, then **how can I protect my code so that no one can play with that**.

Comment: you cannot hide your source code, at least not with cordova html/js apps. regular android apps would be hard to dissect, but even they are not impossible (usually) to pluck a URL using something like bluestacks over softice or a rooted phone. you can't hide the login URL either, that will appear on router logs. in short, you can't do either things you "need" to do; plan accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One huge problem is that you're using http to send the login credentials to the server.  Anyone capturing packets on the network can get a user's login info and account data.  Always always always use https.  As for preventing requests from clients not using the app, you might consider adding some kind of cryptographically signed tag to the request payload that only the app can generate correctly.  I'm not sure I feel comfortable suggesting a particular scheme here, but hopefully some stack overflow users more well versed in security can provide some suggestions.  To your last question, hiding your login url is going to be a lost cause, but if you have some .js file on your server that's handling login validation and you don't want an adversary to be able to inspect it, just make it forbidden.  If you're doing any login validation on the client side, then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed it to HTTPS. I am doing login validation on server side. Also including JS file only when user validation is completed. I am too bad at cryptography part. Could you please explain little more. any other suggestion would be helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: The reason I said I wasn't really comfortable suggesting anything is that only accepting requests coming from your app is a hard --some might say impossible-- problem.  Validating a user can be done securely because each user has secret information, namely their login and password, than can verify that they are who they say they are.  If you want to verify that a request is coming from an instance of the app, and not some other web client, the app needs to have some kind of secret information.  For example, the app could have a "secret" key, and then sign outgoing requests with that key...

Comment: The problem with doing this is that someone who decompiles the app will be able to get the secret key.  Maybe you should think about whether allowing a non-app client to interact with the server really breaks your security model.  Sure, as an attacker, I could write javascript to send a request to your login api, but if I don't have any user credentials, I won't be able to get any compromising data back.  If you are really interested in making this work, there are a number of posts on Stack Overflow which have what I would argue are imperfect solutions, but you are welcome to check them out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. it really helps a lot.